# Timer is not updating firebase database in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am coming to an issue where I have implement a way to get the timer and when the game is over, I want to update the timer to my firebase database. I debug my method below, I am getting the date, but my firebase url (database) is not updating, quite yet. Is there a way I can solve by my code below? thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

```
        public void TrackTimer()
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://MY_PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/timer/timer/time.json");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {

            string time = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
            timeTrack = time; 
            streamWriter.Write(time);

        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        }

    }
```

Comment: No expert but you seem to never actually send the webrequest..? Or your methods might be blocking calls so the whole app freezes until the request is done. Try to rather use [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) in a [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Comment: hey @derHugo sorry for the late response. But, Can you please show me an implementation of how it is working with my code above? thanks

Comment: @derHugo, I think it is blocking calls. Because when I debug in my method, I receive the time when I watch for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Firebase expert.

But instead of direct Http requests I would rather use the dedicated [Firebase Unity SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start)and then you can simply follow the manual for [Retrieving Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data) and [Save Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data). I would assume you are using a "Realtime Database" for now.

First you always need to initialize your reference

```
public class FirebaseController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    DatabaseReference reference

    private void Start() 
    {

        // Set these values before calling into the realtime database.
        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.firebaseio.com/");

        // If usig restricted access then also do
        //FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12FileName("YOUR-FIREBASE-APP-P12.p12");
        //FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorServiceAccountEmail("SERVICE-ACCOUNT-ID@YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
        //FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12Password("notasecret");

        // Get the root reference location of the database.
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    }

    ...
}
```

#### Save data

1. If using JSON you need the according structure for your data as c# classes. Since I don't know your data structure I will just go with the examples from the Firebase manual here

   ```
   // I would always make these classes serializable so you can directly 
   // also see, edit and save them via the Inspector
   [Serializable]
   public class User 
   {
       public string username;
       public string email;

       public User() 
       {
       }

       public User(string username, string email) 
       {
           this.username = username;
           this.email = email;
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can save the data as json like

   ```
   private void writeNewUser(string userId, string name, string email) 
   {
       User user = new User(name, email);
       string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(user);

       reference.Child("users").Child(userId).SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
   }
   ```
2. Or instead use the full path in the firebase structure to only set a single value without the need for a JSON and according class in c# using

   ```
    reference.Child("users").Child(userId).Child("username").SetValueAsync(name);
   ```

#### Retrieving Data

For retrieving you do the same

```
reference.Child("users").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => 
{
    if (task.IsFaulted) 
    {
        // Handle the error...
    }
    else if (task.IsCompleted) 
    {
        DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
        // Do something with snapshot...

        // Again either using a JSON
        var user = JsonUtility.FromJson<User>(snapshot.Child(userId).GetRawJsonValue());
        var username = user.username;

        // OR using the path to get a single value
        var username = (string)snapshot.Child(userId).Child("username").Value();


        // Now do something with the received data
    }
});
```

**Note**: As I have seen it quite often here on SO there is also a little issue with [threading](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html) and `ContinueWith` end on a thread where you can't call any Unity API. So you should probably rather go for [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) instead

---

*As said I'm no firebase expert and only trying to understand and provide an example following the linked guides ... no warranty that this is how these methods really work ;)*